# Как сделать редирект с поддомена на домен, без указания домена

Tags: mod-rewrite

Как сделать редирект с поддомена на домен, без указания домена?

Нашел как сделать редирект с поддомена на домен с указанием домена

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).site.ru$
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1?region=%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

И как сделать редирект с www на без www и без указания домена

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Пробовал сделать так, но он перекидывает на .ru/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.+)\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```